# Parameterless aggregate operator 'Max' is not supported over projections

Tags: linq

Trying to get the max value from Union Query through LINQ

```
var query = (from x in db.GHProgresses select new {A=x.PatentCounter})
                     .Union(from y in db.YUMasters select new { A=y.PatentCounter }).Max();
```

Below is the err

> Parameterless aggregate operator 'Max' is not supported over
>   projections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared an *anonymous type* `new {A=x.PatentCounter}` which can't be maximized by default. Add a projection:

```
var query =  (from x in db.GHProgresses 
            select new { A = x.PatentCounter })
       .Union(from y in db.YUMasters 
            select new { A = y.PatentCounter })
       .Max(item => item.A); // <- Max of A
```

Comment: Yes Thanks. Working now!